# Ruby: execute shell command 'echo' with '-n' option

Tags: ruby, macos, shell

I'd like to run the following shell command from Ruby, which copies a string into the clipboard (on OS X), 'n' is suppressing the line break after the string caused by `echo`:

```
echo -n foobar | pbcopy
```

—> *works, fine, now the clipboard contains "foobar"*

I've tried the following, but all of them always copy the option '-n' as well into the clipboard:

```
%x[echo -n 'foobar' | pbcopy]
%x[echo -n foobar | pbcopy]
system "echo -n 'foobar' | pbcopy"
system "echo -n foobar | pbcopy"
exec 'echo -n "foobar" | pbcopy'
`echo -n "foobar" | pbcopy`
IO.popen "echo -n 'foobar' | pbcopy"
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `-n` is only understood by the bash built-in `echo` command; when you say `%x[...]` (or any of your other variations on it), the command is fed to `/bin/sh` which will act like a POSIX shell even if it really is `/bin/bash`. The solution is to explicitly feed your shell commands to bash:

```
%x[/bin/bash -c 'echo -n foobar' | pbcopy]
```

You will, of course, need to be careful with your quoting on whatever `foobar` really is. The `-c` switch essentially tells `/bin/bash` that you're giving it an inlined script:

> **-c** *string*
>   If the **-c** option is present, then commands are read from *string*.
>   If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional
>   parameters, starting with **$0**.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I was after. The string I'm copying is a user specified password and usually goes into a password field which is the reason why I can't have a line break copied as well, since it would not necessarily ever show up as such, but rather as an extra character. Would you have another suggestion for this case?

Comment: @polarblau: If you're slinging a password around then opening `pbcopy` using one of the `popen` approaches and sending the password in via stdin might be more reliable as you wouldn't have to worry about quotes. Tin Man has an example of using stdin and `Open3.popen3()`.

Comment: Wouldn't `%x[/bin/echo -n foobar | pbcopy]` be easier? (As an aside, `%x[echo -n foobar | pbcopy]` seems to work okay for me.)

Comment: @matt: Yeah, the `%x[...]` thing works and is nice and simple. The problem is that "foobar" might actually be "ha'ha$PATH" or some such mess (it is a password after all) so you have to make sure that everything is properly escaped, opening a pipe to `pbcopy` directly avoids that problem.

Answer (score 6):

Because `echo` behaves differently in different shells and in `/bin/echo`, it's recommended that you use `printf` instead.

No newline:

```
%x[printf '%s' 'foobar' | pbcopy]
```

With a newline:

```
%x[printf '%s\n' 'foobar' | pbcopy]
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be reinventing a wheel.

IRB_Tools and Utility_Belt, which are both used to tweak IRB, provide an ability to use the clipboard. Both are collections of existing gems, so I did a quick search using `gem clipboard -r` and came up with:

```
clipboard (0.9.7)
win32-clipboard (0.5.2)
```

Looking at RubyDoc.info for [clipboard](http://rubydoc.info/gems/clipboard/0.9.7/frames) reveals:

> clipboard
>
> Access the clipboard and do not care if the OS is Linux, MacOS or Windows.
>
> Usage
>
> You have Clipboard.copy,
>
> Clipboard.paste and
>
> Clipboard.clear
>
> Have fun ;)

---

EDIT: If you check the source on the linked page, for the Mac you'll see for copy:

```
def copy(data)
  Open3.popen3( 'pbcopy' ){ |input,_,_| input << data }
  paste
end
```

and for paste you'll see:

```
def paste(_ = nil)
  `pbpaste`
end
```

and clear is simply:

```
def clear
  copy ''
end
```

Those should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I might have a look at the source but the gem might be a little overkill for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This might look like an ugly workaround, but I'm pretty sure it'll work:

Create an executable file called myfoobar.sh containing the line you want to execute.

```
#! /bin/sh
echo -n foobar | pbcopy
```

Then invoke that file from ruby.

Comment: This will only work if `/bin/sh` is bash (or some other shell whose `echo` understands `-c`) and if it is configured to act like bash rather than a strict POSIX shell. `/bin/sh` is often configured to act like a strict POSIX shell. If you said `#!/bin/bash`, OTOH, then you'd get more consistent results with the `echo -n`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid an extra file in this case anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sutil for correct setup:

```
    $ ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Comment: This command is about how to [_"install your public key in a remote machine's authorized_keys"_](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id), but the question is about copying a string onto the clipboard. Could you please explain how this solved the problem?